# Como hago para validar que mi programa de maquina expendedora acepte monedas de 1 2 5 y 10 pesos y billetes de 20 50 y 100 pesos

Tags: java

**texto en negrita**
Buenas noches tengo un problema  estoy haciendo un pograma  que simule una maquina expendedora de productos las condiciones son las siguientes 
que acepte monedas de 1 2 5 y 10 pesos
que acepte  billetes de 100 50 y 20 pesos
mi problema es que cuando ingreso una cantidad toma el valor que ingreso, por ejemplo si ingreso 15  toma ese valor  me gustaria saber como puedo restringir eso ya que solo acepta monedas especificas

este es mi codigo:

import java.io.*;

public class maquinaexpendedora {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufEntrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int a1;
    int a2;
    int a3;
    int a4;
    int b1;
    int b2;
    int b3;
    int b4;
    int billete;
    int billete1;
    int billete2;
    int c1;
    int c2;
    int c3;
    int c4;
    int moneda;
    int moneda1;
    int moneda2;
    int moneda3;
    int opc;
    int total;
    a1 = 8;
    a2 = 10;
    a3 = 12;
    a4 = 15;
    b1 = 18;
    b2 = 20;
    b3 = 25;
    b4 = 30;
    c1 = 7;
    c2 = 5;
    c3 = 22;
    c4 = 21;
            moneda = 0;
            moneda1 = 0;
            moneda2 = 0;
            moneda3 = 0;
            billete = 0;
            billete1 = 0;
            billete2 = 0;


    System.out.println("Esta Maquina solo acepta Monedes de $1.00 2.00 5.00 10.00");
    System.out.println("Esta Maquina solo acepta Billetes de $20.00 50.00 100.000");
    System.out.println("**************************************");
    System.out.println("Ingrese la Opcion del producto deseado");
    System.out.println("1.-A1:Nito $8.00");
    System.out.println("2.-A2:Donas espolvoreadas $10.00");
    System.out.println("3.-A3:Donas $12.00");
    System.out.println("4.-A4:Roles de canela $15.00");
    System.out.println("5.-B1:Mantecadas $18.00");
    System.out.println("6.-B2:Rebanadas $20.00");
    System.out.println("7.-B3:Panque de nuez $25.00");
    System.out.println("8.-B4:Colchones $30.00");
    System.out.println("9.-C1:Bimbuñuelos $7.00");
    System.out.println("10.-C2:Multigrano $5.00");
    System.out.println("11.-C3:Conchas $22.00");
    System.out.println("12.-C4:Bimbolete $21.00");
    System.out.println("**************************************");
    opc = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
    switch (opc) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
                    if (total>a1) {
            total = total-a1;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-a1;
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>a2) {
            total = total-a2;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-a2;
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");

        try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>a3) {
            total = total-a3;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-a3;
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");

        try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>a4) {
            total = total-a4;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-a4;
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>b1) {
            total = total-b1;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-b1;
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>b2) {
            total = total-b2;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-b2;
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>b3) {
            total = total-b3;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-b3;
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>b4) {
            total = total-b4;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-b4;
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>c1) {
            total = total-c1;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-c1;
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>c2) {
            total = total-c2;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-c2;
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>c3) {
            total = total-c3;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-c3;
        break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println("Ingrese el dinero");
                    try{
        moneda = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        moneda3 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete1 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
        billete2 = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
        total = moneda+moneda1+moneda2+moneda3+billete+billete1+billete2;
        if (total>c4) {
            total = total-c4;
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
            System.out.println("Su cambio es:$"+total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recoja su producto");
        }
        total = total-c4;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias ser claro con el problema que tienes, y por favor pega solo la parte relevante del codigo. mira [mcve]

Comment: Además dado que estás trabajando con un lenguaje de programación orientado a objetos, deberías intentar programar orientado a objeto, así te evitas además tanto código en un solo archivo y puedes reutilizarlo de mejor manera

Answer (score 1):

Ok, para empezar, tienes mucho código repetido, pero creo que vas por buen camino. A continuación unas recomendaciones y al final espero poder contestar tu pregunta:

1. Cuando postees una pregunta, intenta formatear todo el código para que se vea bien. Yo empecé a modificarlo, pero me di por vencido por que es mucho código.
2. Intenta poner un ejemplo corto de la parte en donde tienes dudas o problemas para que sea más fácil y puntual ayudarte.

Respecto a tu código:

1. Cuando declares varias variables del mismo tipo, no tienes que hacerlo en diferentes líneas, puedes hacerlo en una sola línea:

   ```
   int a1, a2, a3, a4;
   ```
2. Cuando tus variables vayan a tener un valor de inicio, puedes declararlas e inicializarlas:

   ```
   int a1 = 8, a2 = 10, a3 = 12, a4 = 15;
   ```
3. El mayor código que tienes repetido es en la parte de los `case`. Toda esa sección desde donde pides el dinero hasta donde calculas `total`, es el mismo código para todos tus casos. Te recomiendo que saques esa parte y la pongas antes del `switch`.
4. En esta sección (donde pides el dinero) es en donde podrás solucionar tu problema:

A mi parecer no necesitas tantas variables de monedas y billetes, de hecho no necesitas ninguna. Podrías hacer algo así:

```
dinero = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
if (checarSiDineroValido(dinero)) {
    total += dinero;
    ...
```

siempre y cuando `total` sea inicializado con cero. En esta sección podrás ver que agregué un método que se llama `checarSiDineroValido`. En este método podrías tener una validación para revisar si lo que ingresó el usuario realmente es una moneda o billete aceptable y lo que regresaría el método simplemente sería un `true` o un `false`.

Después de esto es cuando podrías poner el switch para verificar que el monto que tienes en el total es suficiente para comprar el producto o no. Es decir:

```
if (checarSiDineroValido(dinero)) {
    total += dinero;
    switch (opc) {
    ...
```

Seguramente te estarás preguntando "¿qué pasa si el dinero no es válido?". Lo que harías en el `else` es poner un mensaje indicándole al usuario que no es aceptable o lo introdujo y después volver a pedir el dato. Esto se hace con un ciclo. Es decir podría ser algo como:

```
boolean valido = false;
do {
    dinero = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
    if (checarSiDineroValido(dinero)) {
        total += dinero;
        switch (opc) {
        ...
        (dentro de tus casos revisar si el monto es suficiente)
            valido = true;
        (si no es suficiente entonces)
            valido = false
        ...
        }
        if (!valido)
            "mesaje para que ponga más dinero"
    } else {
        "mensaje de que no es válido"
        valido = false;
    }
} while (!valido);
```

No puse todo el código para que te diviertas un rato, pero creo que con lo que te puse como pseudocodigo puedes avanzar y resolver tu problema.

Espero que esto te ayude.